# Conflito com JS wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Estou aprendendo a transformar um site em tema do wordpress, mas me deparei com um erro que não consigo solucionar:

Alguns plugins necessitam que eu tenha no HEAD o código 
esse código adiciona os JS do WP, e entra em conflito com o JS que usei pra desenvolver o projeto.
E se eu excluir o JS que usei no projeto, as funções que utilizavam ele param de funcionar... Alguém pode me ajudar, como faço pra reestabelecer as funções usando os JS do wordpress?

Comment: Posta os erros de conflito que aparecem no teu console

Comment: Utilize `wp_deregister_script` para remover o antigo e `wp_register_script` para adicionar o novo.

Comment: wp_deregister_script e wp_register_script deu certo, obrigado!